# How to deploy serverless file to AWS from bitbucket pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a serverless template using bitbucket pipeline. I have provided the sls deploy command as such `sls deploy --stage ${environmentName} --cloudformationStackDynamoDB $dynamodbEventStoreStackName --componentName ${componentName} --partName ${partName} --eventBusName $eventBusName --region ${awsRegion} || exit`

But I get this error when the pipeline reaches the step to deploy the serverless.yml file `"Error:Cannot resolve serverless.yml: "service" property is not accessible (configured behind variables which cannot be resolved at this stage)"`

Below is the content of serverless.yml

```
service:
  name: ${opt:stage}-${opt:componentName}-${opt:partName}-stream

plugins:
  - "@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript"
  - serverless-plugin-resource-tagging
  #- serverless-plugin-optimize
  #- serverless-offline
  # - serverless-plugin-warmup

# custom:
#   # Enable warmup on all functions (only for production and staging)
#   warmup:
#       enabled: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x

  stackName: ${self:service.name}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - logs:Create*
        - logs:Get*
      Resource: "*"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:*
      Resource: "*"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - events:PutEvents
      Resource: "*" #TODO - apply pattern */eventbus-name
  environment:
    ENVIRONMENT: ${opt:stage}
    COMPONENT_NAME: ${opt:componentName}
    PART_NAME: ${opt:partName}
    EVENTBUS_NAME: ${opt:eventBusName} #TODO - supply this as part of the CICD build
  stackTags:
    COMPONENT_NAME: ${opt:componentName}
    STAGE: ${opt:stage}

functions:
  default:
    handler: src/lambda.streamHandler
    name: ${self:provider.stackName}
    events:
      - stream: ${cf:${opt:cloudformationStackDynamoDB}.DynamoDBTableEventsStreamArn}
    timeout: 30
```

I don't understand why the error says "service" property is not accessible because it is defined in the template file itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you share which version of Serverless are you using? In newest version, object notation with `service: name: <actual name>` is no longer supported and might cause trouble. Does the same deployment method work for you locally?

Comment: `serverless --version
Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)
Framework Core: 2.72.3 (local)
Plugin: 5.5.4
SDK: 4.3.2
Components: 3.18.2`

Yes, it works when I run setup locally.